# I want the user to enter five numbers and then output the sum in the end

Tags: c++

I have used a loop for that:

```
    int number1;
    int sum = 0;

    for(int i=1; i<6; i++) {
        cout << "Enter number:\n";
        cin >> number1;
        sum += number1;
    }

    cout << sum;

    cout << "Total Sum is = " << sum << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

How I can print the first statement like the following?

"Enter first number" 
Enter Second number" and so on

Comment: You could display the index, maybe? `cout << "Enter number " << i << ":\n";`

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you are reading numbers (or any value for that matter), you must check the stream-state (see: [std::basic_istream](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream) *State Functions*). You have four stream states you must test following every input:

- `.bad()` or `.eof()`. If `badbit` is set, an unrecoverable error occurred, and if `eofbit` is set, there is nothing more to read (you can combine both into a single test that exits if either are set)
- `.fail()` is set when a read error occurs, such as the user entering `"FIVE"` instead of `5` where integer input is expected. You handle `failbit` being set by calling `.clear()` to clear `failbit` and then call `ignore()` to empty the characters causing the failure before your next read attempt, and finally
- `.good()` - valid input was received from the user, you can proceed to the next input.

By validating your input here, you can *Require* the user provide five valid integer values for you to sum. Do not use a `for` loop, instead use a `while` (or `do .. while();`) and only increment your counter when good input is received.

Putting that altogether, you can do:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main (void) {

    int number = 0,
        sum = 0;
    const char *label[] = { "first", "second", "third", "fourth", "fifth" };

    while (number < 5)      /* Loop continually until 5 int entered */
    {
        int tmp;            /* Temporary int to fill with user-input */
        std::cout << "\nenter " << label[number] << " number: ";
        if (! (std::cin >> tmp)) {             /* Check stream state */
            /* If eof() or bad() exit */
            if (std::cin.eof() || std::cin.bad()) {
                std::cerr << "  (User canceled or unrecoverable error)\n";
                return 1;
            }
            else if (std::cin.fail()) {         /* If failbit */
                std::cerr << "  error: invalid input.\n";
                std::cin.clear();               /* Clear failbit */
                /* Extract any characters that remain unread */
                std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            }
        }
        else {  /* On successful read of int, add to sum, increment number */
            sum += tmp;
            number++;
        }
    }

    std::cout << "\nsum: " << sum << '\n';
}
```

Now your code will gracefully handle an invalid input without exiting just because a stray character was entered.

**Example Use/Output**

When you write an input routine, go try and break it. Enter invalid data and make sure you handle all error cases correctly. If something doesn't work right, go fix it. Repeat until you input routine can handle all corner cases as well as the cat stepping on the keyboard:

```
./bin/sumintlabel
```

Session transcript:

```
enter first number: 3

enter second number: four five six seven!!
  error: invalid input.

enter second number: 4

enter third number: 5

enter fourth number: 6

enter fifth number: 7

sum: 25
```

Form good habits now regarding handling input; it will pay dividends for the rest of your programming career. Let me know if you have questions.

Comment: If you are going to downvote a technically correct answer, have the integrity to leave a comment. It is truly sad we can't treat each other better than this on StackOverflow.

Comment: I have been writing my own wrappers that take care of whether user input are integers or not. Are you saying that `cin.fail()` could take care of that for me?

Comment: @user18348324 - the `fail()` stream state indicates a failed conversion into the type of variable you are attempting to fill. When the stream state is set to `fail`, you then extract the characters causing the failure using either `std::ignore` or manually advancing a character at a time until you are beyond the character causing failure.  Review the states at [std::basic_ios::rdstate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/rdstate)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `switch()`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::string;

int main() {
    int number1;
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
        string num;
        switch(i) {
            case 1:
                num = "first";
                break;
            case 2:
                num = "second";
                break;
                //and 3 4 5 like this
        }
        cout << "Enter " << num << " number:\n";
        cin >> number1;
        sum += number1;
    }
    cout << "Total Sum is = " << sum << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

or you can use struct or containers like vector (in fact you have to use containers if you want to get a huge number of data.)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to print the words "first"... until "fifth", then I'd do it like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int number1;
    int sum = 0;
    string positions[5] = {"first", "second", "third", "fourth", "fifth"};
    for(int i = 0; i<5; i++) {
        cout << "Enter the " << positions[i] << " number:" << endl;
        cin >> number1;
        sum += number1;
    }
    cout << "Total Sum is = " << sum << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

I used an array of strings to display the words and changed the *for* loop to start at 0m, so that we can go through the array positions and add the five numbers as well. If you just want to use: 1st, 2nd, 3rd... then you could change the *for* loop to what it was and do:

```
cout << "Enter the " << i << "st" << " number:" << endl;
```

But for this, you would have to use the *if* statement to print the right endings ("st", "rd", and "nd"). I think it would take longer for it to run, but it’s milliseconds, so we wouldn't even notice, hahaha.