# I'm trying to make it so that if an invalid value is inputted into a variable the user gets a chance to reenter. Why isn't this working?

Tags: c++

This is for one of the practice problems in the book I'm using to learn C++. I'm new to programming. This is the code with the issue I'm having:

```
int main()
{
    int playercount = 0; //amount of games won
    int compcount = 0;
    int draws = 0;
    bool invalidvalue = false;
    int i = 0; //keeps track of number of games

    cout << "Enter in an integer to help me play: ";
    
    
    int val;
    cin >> val;
        while (cin.good())
        {
            int it = 0;
            while (computer_choices.size() < 12)
            {

                val = choicegenerator(val);
                switch (val)
                {
                case 0:
                    computer_choices.push_back("rock");
                    break;
                case 1:
                    computer_choices.push_back("paper");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    computer_choices.push_back("scissors");
                    break;
                }

                val = it;
                ++it;
            }
            break;
        }
    
    while (!(cin.good()))
    {
        cout << "error: invalid value\nPlease enter an integer value: ";
        cin.clear();
        cin >> val;
    }
```

The problem I'm having is with the last while statement. It doesn't actually take any input, it just loops back to the beginning over and over. I've tried changing it to while (val == 0) and trying changing it to an if statement, getting rid of cin.clear(), formatting it differently, putting it somewhere else etc but the same thing happens every time and I'm stuck. I've been googling it a lot and reading posts here and it seems everyone says to do some variation of the way I'm already doing it so I'm having a hard time understand why mine isn't working.

Comment: The invalid character is still in the input stream, and `cin >> val` attempts to read it again, and fails again. You may be looking for [`ingore`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) method.

Comment: What is `computer_choices`? Please provide a [mre].

Comment: [Example of handling input with `std::cin`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63212960/3422102) may be helpful. You need to handle 3 cases for every input (1) good input, (2) `.eof` or `.bad` (unrecoverable) or (3) `.fail` improper value, empty stream and try again.

Comment: Try   `while (in.good())` instead. Your while expression is wrong. You don't what to loop while the stream has an error. This will loop endlessly.

Comment: i tried using the ignore method, but then i had other problems. If I have it ignore too few characters then it just repeats over and over a few times, and if it ignores too many then the program just terminates after the next statement after the loop.