# Integer input from user

Tags: c++

I am writing a program in C++ that requires taking in integers from the user.

These may come in one of two forms:

1. Single-input integers of the form 'X\n', where X is the user input. These get put into regular integer primitives.
2. Multi-input integers of the form 'X X X X X\n', where X is the user input. These are parsed into an array of integers.

Here is an example of each:

Multi-input line

```
void UI::inputMatrix(Entries** matrix, int rows, int cols){
    for (int i = 0 ; i < rows; i++){
        std::cout << "Row " << i+1 << ": ";
        for (int j = 0 ; j < cols ; j++){
            std::cin >> matrix[i][j];
        }
    }
    std::cout << endl;
}
```

Single-input line

```
    std::cout << std::endl << "Please input the digit corresponding to your option: ";
    std::cin >> m_operation;
```

I've found that with `std::cin` functionality, this works perfectly fine unless the user begins to (a) not follow instructions or (b) type non-sensical input.

What is the best way to take this sort of integer input from the user?

I am considering writing my own program that parses string input from the user using `std::getline()` into the integers I require, and throws an error otherwise, but I really like the `std::cin` functionality available for taking in inputs into my array.

UPDATE:

Here is my solution:

```
istringstream readInput(){
    
    string s;
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    getline(cin, s);
    istringstream buffer(s);
    
    return buffer;
}
```

The `istringstream` can be used to put inputs into the designated locations and also acts as a boolean if an unexpected input is encountered.

Comment: Read lines with `getline`, parse them with `istringstream`

Comment: @paddy Do you mean that I would read lines from `cin` into a `string` object, construct an `istringstream` with that `string` object, and read from that `istringstream` into my `int` objects?

Comment: Yes, you use a `istringstream` object the same way you use `cin`.

Comment: Your solution assumes that the input is out-of-sync with the user’s _press ENTER after every input_ expectation. The only time things get out of sync is when you mix formatted and unformatted input. Always read input with `getline()` and things stay synchronized.

Comment: For full error-handling with `std::cin` for integer input, you can see the answer to [Hi I want user to enter 5 numbers and then output the sum in the end](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63212960/3422102). If you have the option, `std::getline` with `std::stringstream` makes things easier (especially when reading multiple values per-line, such as with a .csv or tab-separated input where validating the contents of a line is important -- you can read multiple values with `std::cin`, but cannot identify the line-end, without reading more than `int` values, due to `std::cin` ignoring whitespace)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin if you could direct your expertise with `std::stringstream` to my question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74936806/how-can-i-correctly-keep-track-of-stream-position , it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good way to parse line-based input is to read lines using `std::getline` and then use `std::istringstream` to read formatted input from each line the same way you would do with `std::cin`.

For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    int line_num = 1;
    for (std::string line; std::getline(std::cin, line); ++line_num)
    {
        std::istringstream iss(line);
        for (int value; iss >> value; )
        {
            std::cout << "Line " << line_num << ": " << value << "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Input:

```
1 2
3 4 5 fail 6
7
nope
8
```

Output:

```
Line 1: 1
Line 1: 2
Line 2: 3
Line 2: 4
Line 2: 5
Line 3: 7
Line 5: 8
```

Comment: `std::getline` with `std::stringstream` is a bit easier for new users to follows that checking the three required steam-states and handling offending characters with `std::ignore`. Good solution.

Answer (score 0):

## input <int...> from the user

You have correctly observed that user input always ends with <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Good job!

You have also identified two specific patterns you wish to accept. This is fabulous!

### The Algorithm

is very simple:

1. Ask the user for desired input.
2. Read a line of input
3. **Convert the line to what you expect**.
4. Complain (and maybe quit) if step 2 failed.

I know. Too simple.
But, alas, never obvious enough.

### 0. Ask for (and get) a line of user input

You have already identified this utility. (Excellent!) May I suggest this little improvement / correction:

```
std::istringstream ask_user_input( const std::string & prompt )
{
  std::cout << prompt;
  std::string s;
  getline( std::cin, s );
  return std::istringstream( s );
}
```

This automatically gives every user input the desired line-oriented synchrony. Ask for something, get the user’s <kbd>Enter</kbd>-terminated response.

BTW, I learned something from you. I would have just returned a `std::string`. Returning the `std::istringstream` is brilliant!

### 1. Single-input integers of the form 'X\n', where X is the user input.

Write a function:

```
int ask_integer( const std::string & prompt )
{
  auto input = ask_user_input( prompt );
  int n;
  if ((input >> n) and (input >> std::ws).eof())
    return n;
  throw error( "Expected an integer value" );  // (see end of post)
}
```

This is as easy to use as it looks:

```
int age = ask_integer( "age? " );
```

You will note that I have modified the input to be a bit forgiving with whitespace, but things like “`12yrs`” is still not valid.

If you wish, you can even add minimum and maximum checks (or any other kind of validation) to your little helper function, increasing its utility:

```
int age = ask_integer( "age? ", 0, 120 );
```

(Modifying the `ask_integer()` function to take optional bounds arguments is an exercise left to the reader.)

### 2. Multi-input integers of the form 'X X X X X\n', where X is the user input.

You may guess, correctly, that this is a variation on the last.

```
void ask_array_of_integer( const std::string & prompt, int * xs, std::size_t N )
{
  auto input = ask_user_input( prompt );
  for (std::size_t n = 0;  n < N;  n++)
    if (!(input >> xs[n]))
      break;
  if (!input or !(input >> std::ws).eof())
    throw error( "Expected ", N, " integers" );
}

template <std::size_t N>
void ask_array_of_integer( const std::string & prompt, int (&xs)[N] )
{
  ask_array_of_integer( prompt, xs, N );
}
```

Again, usage is simplicity:

```
int point[3];
ask_array_of_integer( "x y z? ", point );
```

Or:

```
int * xs = new int[5];
...
ask_array_of_integer( "5 ints? ", xs, 5 );
```

Observe how the workhorse is the C-style function. The C++ template overload is just an inline nicety.

### You can even give the user multiple chances to get it right

We *could* just write a loop... with `try` and `catch` blocks...

But I’m just gonna get fancy here with a recursive template function taking a lambda, lol.

```
template <typename Lambda>
auto try_N_times( std::size_t N, Lambda f ) -> decltype(f())
{
  try
  {
    return f();
  }
  catch (const std::exception & e)
  {
    if (N > 1)
    {
      std::cout << e.what() << "\n";
      return try_N_times( N-1, f );
    }
    throw error( "Too many failures: ", e.what() );
  }
}
```

Here is the payoff for that madness: We can now be somewhat more forgiving with user input in a succinct, readable way.

```
int n = try_N_times( 3, [](){ return ask_integer( "n? " ); } );

int xs[5];
try_N_times( 3, [&xs](){ ask_array_of_integer( "xs? ", xs ); } );
```

### error(...)

You can handle error processing however you like, of course.
Personally, I like this:

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

struct error : public std::runtime_error
{
  template <typename...Args>
  error( Args...args ) : std::runtime_error( join( args... ) ) { }
  
private:
  template <typename...Args>
  std::string join( Args...args )
  {
    std::ostringstream ss;
    (ss << ... << args);
    return ss.str();
  }
};
```

I do tend to keep it in an appropriate namespace, though.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Here is where I ended up (keep in mind that this is a function inside a class that is responsible for greater input handling): ` void UI::readInput(const InputType inputType){
retry:
    string s;
    getline(cin, s);
    if (!isValidInput(s, inputType)){
        cout << "Invalid input. Try again: ";
        goto retry;
    }
    m_buffer = istringstream(s);
} `

Comment: NOOOoooOOOoooo! I complimented you so much, and then you used `goto`. My poor heart.  (LOL)

Comment: I like `goto` and I didn't see another solution. The way you did it with `try` and `catch` is clever, but wordy, and I like to keep it simple.

Comment: That’s honestly fine, but you could easily refactor that into a loop. It won’t pass a code review with `goto`. Remember, CS people like to burn `goto` witches.

Answer (score -1):

I came across this problem before, and the `cin` behavior really confuses me, if `cin` tries to read alpha into an integer, `cin` will not read until you manually use `clear()` function or another trick.

So here is my solution, it just works, maybe not elegant :)

```
vector<int> matrix(size);
int temp;

while (cin >> temp)
{
  matrix.push_back(temp);
  if (cin.peek() == '\n') break;
}
cin.clear();
```

Comment: `std::cin` with `>>` is for _formatted_ input, and does not observe the fact that **Every User Input Will End With ENTER**. In other words, use _unformatted_ input (string input) every time, then use a `std::istringstream` or something to process that input.