# How can I correctly keep track of stream position?

Tags: c++

I am writing a program which requires me to take in `double` inputs from the user in a very specific way, so I'm learning about streams.

In the end, my goal is to force the user to format their input in the way I desire, which is:

`2.0 3.0 4.0` -> doubles (or integers) with spaces in between and no trailing spaces

I've been using a `std::istringstream` to read inputs in a way akin to the following example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int a[5] = {0};
    
    while (1){
        cout << "Input: ";
        string s;
        getline(cin, s);
        istringstream buffer(s);
        
        for (int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++)
            buffer >> a[i];
        
        for (int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++)
            cout << a[i] << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

My question is about the following terminal input/output:

```
Input: 1 2 3 4 5
1 2 3 4 5 
Input: a b c d e
0 2 3 4 5
```

Why is the output for the characters being put into integers the way it is?

Here is another example:

```
Input: 5 6 7 8 9
5 6 7 8 9 
Input: a b c d e
0 6 7 8 9
```

It seems to be defaulting to `0` for the first encountered character, and then reusing the rest of the stream, which is why I'm asking about stream position.

My expectations:

1. Either it would be the corresponding ASCII numerals.
2. They would all be `0`, since (for a reason that I would like to know), characters inputted from a stream into an integer tend to default to `0`.

I believe the output being the way it is has to do with the stream position, and I would like it explained (along with an answer on the defaulting `0` characters).

Basically, I'm curious about streams and would like to know more about how they're handled, and this seems like a quirk that could highlight that.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy What do you mean? I am writing an application that requires input in the form I described because it is for matrices. I'm being draconian about it and forcing the user to re-input until it is the way I desire. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Key here is to use a `while()` loop instead of a `for()` loop (or only increment the `for` within the block, not as part of the `for` declaration) so you only increment the count when a valid `double` or `int` is read. Since you will allow both types `double` and `int`, read as a `double` which will accept the floating-point or integer form of input. For example `int n = 0; while (n < 5) { if ((buffer >> a[n])) { n++; } else { /* check state, ignore the word causing error, break if buffer empty */ }}`. Then you can loop `for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)` for your print loop.

Comment: `if (buffer >> a[i]) { /* a value was read */ } else { /* an error occurred */ }` Always check input operations for success or failure.

Comment: This is just an example, but thank you @RetiredNinja . I didn't know that there is a boolean attached to `buffer >> a[I]`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin So you're saying to use `buffer >> a[I]` to keep track of the count, so that I can know how much input was created? If so, this is really useful information, though I'm not sure how I would integrate it into my application in the way you described since it involves multiple functions and different handlers.

Comment: Yes, let's say the user enters `1.1 2.2 foo 4.4`. There are only three valid double values you can read. When you attempt `buffer >> a[I]` on `"foo"` `failbit` will be set and no characters would be extracted leaving the position in `buffer` pointing to `"foo"`. You then need to ignore or extract `"foo"` (like using `buffer >> somestring`) before attempting to read again to capture `4.4`. (where `somestring` is just some temp string variable you can use to extract the whitespace separated word that caused `failbit` to be set)

Comment: Why are you letting the user get away with feeding you alphanumeric characters when you expect a floating point value?  Shouldn't you warn the use and ask for proper input values?  In any case, a program should not continue until all of its expected inputs are  valid.

Comment: I see @DavidC.Rankin . My default in that case has been to throw a `stderr` and have the user re-input the data instead of trying to deal with it myself, just to make it explicit for them.

Comment: Yes, you handle the error however you like, generally throwing an error and prompting within the loop for the input again. Your goal is to gracefully-recover from whatever the user did wrong and to provide them an opportunity to get it right. Otherwise, all you are doing is exiting the program on error -- which doesn't get you too far in real-life.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy I'm not. This is not my program. This is an example. Perhaps my question is unclear? My program I'm writing is mentioned at the top. This is a quirk of streams that I noticed that I am, in this question, asking about.

Comment: In other words, since your inputs for doubles are a, b, c, d, e, which are not valid doubles, the rest of the program exhibits undefined behaviour,.  What you see printed out is the best it can do.  You cannot expect anything more.  It is your program only because you posted it.  Don't take it personally.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy I don't believe that's entirely the case, I'll put another example on the question. I'm asking about the stream position specifically.

Comment: In the business we have a saying for the behaviour of your piece of software. it's "garbage in, garbage out" .  I don't see what other example of feeding alphanumeric characters into a program expecting purely numeric input can be expected to behave correctly unless the error is caught and dealt with.

Comment: I'm not sure what this case has to do with stream position. You gave erroneous input, took no action to recover from that (hint. `cin.clear()`) and so all subsequent input failed.

Comment: I'm just a bit confused @MichaëlRoy because as I mentioned, it's characters, into integers. My expectation is that they would be casted as an `(int)` and re-interpreted by their corresponding ASCII numerals.

Comment: @John I had thought that `getline()` "clears" the `cin` input stream? As in, we would only ever be moving forward in the stream, so we would never encounter what came before, because `getline()` gets up until the first '\n' character. That's why I'm asking about stream position

Comment: Why don't you check the position of the stream?  Use buffer.tellg(), as described in the documentation.  The documentation  _is_ available online here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/tellg, among other places.

Comment: That's exactly what I was asking about @MichaëlRoy. Thank you.

Comment: @user18348324 `getline()` does not clear the input stream, only `clear()` does that. but maybe you are misunderstanding what clearing a stream means,

Comment: Maybe you should take another look at the help I gave you on your other thread. I took time to explain how to avoid all these problems.

Comment: I know @Dúthomhas . I was just curious why the problem was occuring in the way it was, not how to resolve it.

Comment: @John I think that I was, but I believe that is, sort of, clarified for me. `getline()` goes up to and reads and discards next '\n' and the stuff stays in the stream, but the stream position is updated to after that '\n'.

Comment: As one followup @MichaëlRoy , do you know why in all the experiments I've tried, `cin.tellg()` always yields `-1` ? Is it because `cin` tends to reside at the very front of the terminal/input box. This contradicts my above comment about how I thought the stream position would work.

Comment: You cannot use `tellg()` or the like on standard streams (`cin`, `cout`, `cerr`, `clog`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the full explanation for your output.

I'm concentrating on the input of `a`.

The first step is that the read fails because `a` is not a valid integer. This puts the `cin` stream into an *error state* and sets `a[i]` to zero.

The next step is that `cin >> a[i];` returns and the program prints the value from step one.

Now the stream is in an error state (from step one) all subsequent reads fail immediately, with no change to any `a[i]`, so the previous values are printed.

So nothing to do with stream position.

Comment: I understand. Thank you. I didn't really know about error states before this. That's been the biggest highlight.

Comment: @user18348324 Great, so don't forget to check for them and use `clear()` to remove them (e.g. `if (!(cin >> a[i])) { cin.clear(); ... }`).

Comment: Two questions. 1. Is it guaranteed that `cin >> a[i];` always set `a[I]` to zero independent of what is read? 2. If an erroneous state is encountered, how can we check for it? From my understanding `cin.fail()` is the standard way. @john

Comment: @user18348324 1. Yes, unless the stream is in an error state. My previous description was not quite correct, the setting to zero actually occurs when the conversion has failed. Also not that this is a change to C++, not sure exactly when, but previously notsetting to zero occurred.

Comment: @user18348324 2. `fail()` only tests for one kind of error (failure to convert), `eof()` and `bad()` are other tests. But generally speaking you test the stream itself, e.g. `while (cin >> x)`. A stream can be used in an `if` or `while` test. If the stream is good it converts to `true`, if it's in an error state it converts to `false`.

Comment: Could you please edit your answer to be fully correct then? I have some other questions, but I think I'll make another post for some final clarifications. It's just about the handling of whitespaces and why certain cases behave the way they do.